# Is There A Way To Print A TornadoFX Stylesheet?

Tags: tornadofx

I'm trying to verify the CSS used in a `Stylesheet` that utilizes custom `cssproperty`s but they don't seem to be working. I can't tell if I'm writing it all correctly and I'd like to check to see what is actually being used. Is there a way to print out a `Stylesheet`?

Edit: To be clear, these are TornadoFX classes, not just plain CSS. I am trying to verify type-safe CSS, not trying to print a CSS file.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. "not trying to print a CSS file" seems to be opposite "see what's being used", as what's being used is the generated CSS.

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom I'm trying to clarify that I'm trying to specifically use TornadoFX and see what CSS is being created. I was downvoted earlier an I think that was because someone thought I was trying to print a direct .css file regardless of TornadoFX involvement. I don't want some random question grader coming in here getting confused between TornadoFX classes and the usual CSS style sheet.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can just create an instance of the Stylesheet and call it's `render()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving my comment to an answer*

To see the CSS that will be generated by a `Stylesheet`, instantiate it and call the its `render()` function:

```kotlin
class MyStyles : Stylesheet {
    ...
}

fun main() {
    println(MyStyles().render())
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! It doesn't have a description in the documentation but I should've at least checked the documentation in the first place.